# Acquiring multiple leases on blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

If I have multiple compute instances that try to acquire a lease on the same blob at the same time, it seems to succeed quite often. I was under the impression that once a lease was given out (and thus, acquired by the client) it should be impossible for another to be given out at the same time?

I hope this is the case, I have been using blob leases as distributed locks in Azure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read This article "Managing Concurrency in Windows Azure with Leases" from the   @Smarx to get the exact answer:

By @Smarx: "A lease is the distributed equivalent of a lock. Locks are rarely, if ever, used in distributed systems, because when components or networks fail in a distributed system, it’s easy to leave the entire system in a deadlock situation. Leases alleviate that problem, since there’s a built-in timeout, after which resources will be accessible again."

http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases

Answer (score 0):

As long as a lease is held, another lease cannot be acquired. But leases expire after a minute if not renewed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was actually using your code from [github](https://github.com/smarx/WazStorageExtensions/blob/master/AutoRenewLease.cs): in the AutoRenewLease.Dispose() method, the lease is manually released. It can happen that one thread releases the lease and a second thread acquires it. The Action that gets passed in is invoked twice.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you share some code or better explain what you're trying to do? If one thread release a lease, another thread *should* be able to acquire it.

Comment: Sure. But the action to invoke should only ever happen once. If two threads use AutoRenewLease, it can happen that one thread has acquired a lease, performed the action and released the lease while at the same time a thread has entered the AutoRenewLease constructor and is able to acquire a second lease. Thus, the action gets invoked twice which should never happen. From the Dispose() method, I removed the _blob.ReleaseLease() line.

Comment: If you remove the ReleaseLease() line, you're holding on to the lease for a full minute for no reason. If that fixes a bug in your code, it means you have a timing bug. (It's like adding a sleep statement to fix something.)